# XSLT is not outputting the correct number of RowDefinition/ColumnDefinition elements to my XML file.

Tags: xml, xaml, xslt

**In XSLT:**

For some strange reason, when I specify a number larger than 9 as param, only 2 RowDefinition/ColumnDefinition elements are output in the resulting XML file.
I use a recursive loop for both.

This is strange, because it perfectly outputs 9 <RowDefinition/> <ColumnDefinition/> elements when I give 9 as param value for rcount/ccount in the call-template of draw-grid. If I give 10 as param, then suddenly I only get only 2 <RowDefinition/> <ColumnDefinition/> elements in my resulting XML file.

Why is this happening? I need 28 rows and 6 cols..

See code:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="draw-grid">
        <!--outputs only 2 RowDefinition elements..-->
        <xsl:with-param name="rcount">10</xsl:with-param>
        <!--works perfectly: I get 9 ColumnDefinition elements-->
        <xsl:with-param name="ccount">9</xsl:with-param>              
        <xsl:with-param name="r">0</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="c">0</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="draw-grid">
    <xsl:param name="rcount"/>
    <xsl:param name="ccount"/>
    <xsl:param name="r"/>
    <xsl:param name="c"/>

    <xsl:element name="Grid">

        <xsl:element name="Grid.RowDefinitions">
            <xsl:call-template name="draw-rows">
                <xsl:with-param name="rcount">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$rcount"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="r">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$r"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:element name="Grid.ColumnDefinitions">
            <xsl:call-template name="draw-cols">
                <xsl:with-param name="ccount">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$ccount"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="c">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$c"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="draw-rows">
    <xsl:param name="rcount"/>
    <xsl:param name="r"/>

    <xsl:if test="$r &lt; $rcount">
        <xsl:element name="RowDefinition"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$r &lt; $rcount">
        <xsl:call-template name="draw-rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="r">
                <xsl:value-of select="$r  + 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="rcount">
                <xsl:value-of select="$rcount"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="draw-cols">
    <xsl:param name="ccount"/>
    <xsl:param name="c"/>

    <xsl:if test="$c &lt; $ccount">
        <xsl:element name="ColumnDefinition"/>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$c &lt; $ccount">
        <xsl:call-template name="draw-cols">
            <xsl:with-param name="c">
                <xsl:value-of select="$c  + 1"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="ccount">
                <xsl:value-of select="$ccount"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Works fine for me, even with 20. Tested with MSXSL.

Comment: Huh.. strange. Well, I am working with EditIx free version. I'll try again..

Comment: I have just downloaded MSXML 4.0 and tried my files on it.. they work, just like you said. Correct number of Cols and Rows. Why doesn't it work with EditIX then?... If anyone knows please?

Answer (score 1):

Result obtained with MSXSL (26,8):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, but what I would like to know is why it will not work in EditIx. I need it to work in EditIx.

Comment: Buggy app? Are you testing it as XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Maybe limitation of free version, i.e. recursion depth? :-)

Comment: @MRSil Can you try testing in 1.0?

Comment: Bizar.. I have just tested in 1.0 with the same editor (EditIx) and the issue has been resolved. Must have something to do with XSLT 2.0.

Comment: That was my suspect. I don't think it's due to XSLT 2.0 itself, because __1st)__ any XSLT 1.0 transform should work for an XSLT 2.0 processor, __2nd)__ I've tested it as XSLT 2.0 and it works the same (Saxon). Even if XSLT 2.0 is stricter in term of data types (respect XSLT 1.0) I think that the failure it's probably due to the fact that you are using a free version. When using free tools (home/personal editions) make sure that you know first all limitations applied. The vendor is always very clear in the differences between different versions.

Comment: Blergh. Well, it was a tool assigned to us by our prof. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't know what to do with this question now. Should someone put an answer on it? I don't really know what a suitable answer could be.

Comment: Just remove your question if you like. I don't care about accepts/upvotes in this case. Make sure to tell your professor that his tool suc## ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with EditIx.

This code works fine in EditIx if your file is an XSLT version 1.0 (see 'version' attribute on the top of the file).
This code also works fine if using the commandline tool MSXML (current version: 4.0).
There seem to be problems with XSLT 2.0 in EditIx Free Version with this particular piece of code.